# How to retrieve hashmap model passed from controller in JSP using javascript

Tags: javascript, java, json, jsp, spring-mvc

I am passing model like below in my controller (below are just an example since I can not paste my actual code).

```
Map<String, MyObject> map = new HashMap<>();
List<String> graphLabel = Arrays.asList("EARTH","MOON");
String data_1 = "[[1,70],[2,104],[3,120],[4,93]]";
String data_2 = "[[1,57],[2,19],[3,87],[4,128]]";

map.put("metaData_1", new MyObject("Day", graphData, data_1));
map.put("metaData_2", new MyObject("Day", graphData, data_1));
```

In my controller I add the above generated map to ViewAndModel like below

```
ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView();
modelAndView.addObject("dataModel", convertToJSON(map));
modelAndView.setViewName("My_JSP_PAGE.jsp");
return modelAndView;
```

Now in my JSP using javascript I need to access this values. How do i need to access the map (**iterating through the keys and retrieve the properties of the MyObjects**) which i have added in the ModelAndView

I have tried below methods , but no luck...I couldn't even get the values on js alert also.

1. Instead of adding map into the ModelAndView add JSON string,

> ```
> private String convertToJSON(Map map) {
>     ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
>     String jsonString = null;
>     try {
>         jsonString = mapper.writeValueAsString(map);
>     } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
>     }
>     return jsonString;
> }
> ```

2. Instead of adding map into the ModelAndView add JSON object,

> ```
> private JSONObject convertToJSON(Map map) {
>     JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
>     jsonObject.putAll(map);
>     return jsonObject; 
> }
> ```

below is the sample jsp where i am trying to fetch these values,

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(retrieveData());
function retrieveData() {
    alert("${dataModel}");
}
</script>
```

Comment: What did `alert` print for two ways in your question?

Comment: Where is `dataModel`? Where is `convertToJSON()`used? Where is the transport of the maps? After which load should retrieveData() be callbacked?

Comment: Thnks JPG and Holger for responding. Got where the issue is. Changing from alert("${dataModel}");  to alert(${dataModel}); solved the issue. @Holger - convertToJSON() was used to here modelAndView.addObject("dataModel", convertToJSON(map));, missed to add that. Now I have edited